# Using Axios.js in a Singleton pattern to serve an object once

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, axios, es6-promise

I am using axios to return a JSON object that is necessary for my module. This is a pretty big object, so I would like to use the singleton pattern to significantly reduce the requests for this object every time it is required.

For example:

```
// This variable holds the JSON object once it is retrieved by axios
var myJsonObject = null;

function fetchMyJsonObject() {
    if (!myJsonObject) {
        // use axios here to fetch
        axios.get('/objects/my-json-object')
             .then(response => {
                 myJsonObject = response.data;
             });
    }
    return myJsonObject;
}
```

The problem here is obvious: axios' requests are asynchronous, so the `return myJsonObject;` line will run before the axios request is completed ,and before the `myJsonObject` variable is assigned the fetched data `response.data;`. So, `myJsonObject` will always be `null`.

I wish to only fetch the `myJsonObject` *once* and store it into a variable that can be served to other client modules if it already exists. If it does not exist, then I wish to fetch it and store it.

How can I restructure this function to achieve this?

Comment: Just store the promise in that variable. You will need to return a promise from the function anyway.

Comment: @Bergi, would you mind demonstrating this code?

Answer (score 1):

Just return the promise object. In the client code, you just need to call on the promise object.

```
var getJsonPromise = null;

    function fetchMyJsonObject() {
        if (!getJsonPromise ) {
            // use axios here to fetch
             getJsonPromise  = axios.get('/objects/my-json-object');
        }
        return getJsonPromise;
    }
```

Client Code

```
fetchMyJsonObject();

getJsonPromise.then(response => // do whatever you want with json data);
```

Comment: No, `myJsonObject` is acquired asynchronously, therfore it cannot be reliably returned. Instead, cache/return the promise returned by `axios.get()`.

Comment: Still no. Always return the cached promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Okay, fingers crossed now. How about now? If this is wrong do you mind indicating what I need to change in the code above?

Comment: That's it, you got it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It gave me new ideas. The client code may be in a different module so the getJsonPromise variable may be unavailable to it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using new ES syntax

```
// This variable holds the JSON object once it is retrieved by axios
var myJsonObject = null;

async function fetchMyJsonObject() {
    try {
        if (!myJsonObject) {
            myJsonObject = await axios.get('/objects/my-json-object');
        }

        return myJsonObject;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```